# SQL LIMIT with WHERE clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is it possible to use LIMIT x with the WHERE clause? **If so, how?**

I'm trying to do this:

```
select * from myVIew LIMIT 10 where type=3;
```

But i get the following error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "where"
LINE 2: where type=3;
        ^
********** Error **********
ERROR: syntax error at or near "where"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 44
```

Comment: Limit the amount of rows returned.

Comment: Why do you have "MySQL" in the title if you are using PostgreSQL?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I had 'SQL' Someone edited it. :/ Thanks, changed it back.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
select * from myVIew  where type=3 LIMIT 10;
```

`Limit` should be after `where clause`.

Syntax :

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
[WHERE]
LIMIT number;
```

Comment: This is not allowed in SQL, only in MySQL

Answer (score 5):

Yes, have you tried this?

```
select * from myVIew  where type=3 LIMIT 10;
```

Look [here for further reference](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-select.html). `LIMIT` is after `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` clauses, which makes total sense if you stop and think about it: first you have to define your base result set (filters and orders), then you limit/page it.

Comment: "...which makes total sense..." wait I thought we were talking about SQL?

Answer (score 2):

```
 select * from myVIew where type=3  LIMIT 10;
```