# A way to delete all printer except %name1% and %name2% with batch script

Tags: batch-file, printing, lan, wmic

I'm searching A way to delete all printer except %name1% and %name2% with batch script on client computer.

Powershell scripts doesn't work for me cause there is old non-updated windows 7 computers on my network.

I tried :

```bash
@echo off
wmic printer where "NOT name like '%PDF24%' AND NOT name like '%Microsoft Print to PDF%'" delete
exit
```

It doesn't work. All printers are deleted.

Can you give me a hand?
:-)

Comment: Tell us the exact names of the printers you wish to keep, preferably a list of all of the printers, and show us your full code, with absolutely no omissions. Please DO NOT post that information in this comment section. Use the [Edit] button, and append it to your question body. _Please also use the formatting tools for all of your code._

Comment: You should be able to adapt this script [How to use printui.exe with a value containing the printer name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7532866/2128947)